# Defined input is not defined ? (What the hex ?)

Tags: javascript

I am having such a strange error. Although I defined "input", the system still said "Hey dude, you didn't define "input", maybe you should go around your code again.". It really made me confused. So, here is my code:

```
 var txt = document.createElement("input");
    txt.type = "text"
    txt.placeholder = "Your answer is: ";
    document.getElementById("form").appendChild(input);
```

Because I am new to javascript please be simple. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: it is you variable you have to add til appendChild(txt).

Comment: i should have called "input" instead of "txt". Sorry for wasting your time

Comment: @KalpeshRajai it was a simple mistake, no need to be so harsh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your appendChild to this

```
var txt = document.createElement("input");
txt.type = "text"
txt.placeholder = "Your answer is: ";
document.getElementById("form").appendChild(txt);
```

Otherwise you are trying to add an undefined object.

Comment: oh my god! i didn't notice that, i guest that maybe i didn't focus enough. So funny! i thought that there must be something bigger.

Answer (score 1):

You need to correct your append child line in your code, because instead of `"txt"` you're adding `"input"` element which is not present in your code.

```
  document.getElementById("form").appendChild(txt);
```

Answer (score 1):

You got the logic correct, except for one part. Currently, you're trying to add an `input` variable but it isn't defined.

Instead, add the `txt` variable you already declared.

```
document.getElementById("form").appendChild(txt);
```